# How to match version substring within overall string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a version substring with regex in the form of v###.##.### or version #.##.###. The number of version numbers doesn't matter and there may or may not be a space after the v or version. This is what I was trying so far but it's not matching in some cases:

```
\bv\s?[\d.]*\b|\bversion\s?[\d.]*\b
```

For example, it matches "version 6.2.11" but not c2000_v6.2.11. I'm relatively new to regex and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do the "or" part as well, so any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: `[\d.]*` for matching a version number is wrong (e.g. it will match 5 dots in a row), something like `\d+(\.\d+)*` would be more accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your pattern can be shortened considerably by implementing an optional non-capturing group so that `v` or `version` could be matched without the need of an alternation.

Next, the first `\b` requires a word boundary but the version information starts after `_` in the second expected match, and `_` is a word char.

You can use

```
(?<![^\W_])v(?:ersion)?\s?[\d.]*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WCCH58/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<![^\W_])` - immediately on the left, there can be no letter or digit
- `v` - a `v` char
- `(?:ersion)?` - an optional `ersion` string
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `[\d.]*` - zero or more digits or dots
- `\b` - a word boundary.